# MAX() not showing expected result in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Really stumped here, so any advice would be much appreciated please.

I in the `clients` table, I have the following records for the client with `ID` = 257:

```
SELECT ref, ID, client_name, data_1 FROM clients WHERE ID = 257

+------+-----+-------------+--------+
| ref  | ID  | client_name | data_1 |
+------+-----+-------------+--------+
| 1123 | 257 | Client257   | 0      |
| 1124 | 257 | Client257   | 163    |
+------+-----+-------------+--------+
```

Now, if I add a simple MAX() to the `ref` field, I get:

```
SELECT MAX(ref), ID, client_name, data_1 FROM clients WHERE ID = 257

+------+-----+-------------+--------+
| ref  | ID  | client_name | data_1 |
+------+-----+-------------+--------+
| 1124 | 257 | Client257   | 0      |
+------+-----+-------------+--------+
```

I should get:

```
+------+-----+-------------+--------+
| ref  | ID  | client_name | data_1 |
+------+-----+-------------+--------+
| 1124 | 257 | Client257   | 163    |
+------+-----+-------------+--------+
```

Can anyone explain this please?  And what should I do to get the desired result?

**EDIT:**

Added the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE clients` as requested by @Ilion:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
 `ref` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `client_name` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
 `data_1` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `last_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 UNIQUE KEY `ref` (`ref`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1135 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: apply max to data_1 and see if you get the desired result

Comment: Are you showing your second query correctly? It looks identical to the first for me

Comment: Your sintax is wrong, you cannot select aggregate attributes and not aggrgated ones together

Comment: Ah, good old MySQL and its willingness to let you shoot yourself in the foot with aggregate functions... If you don't GROUP BY the non-aggregated columns in the query, your results will be unpredictable.

Comment: @DanJ Is there a way that I can add a `GROUP BY` so that I can remove the ID=257 clause and extend to the whole population?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this help?

```
SELECT ref, ID, client_name, data_1 FROM clients WHERE ID = 257 and ref in
    (select max(ref) from clients WHERE ID = 257)
```

Comment: You could safely make that `in` an `=`, since MAX() will only return a single value... :)

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT ref, ID, client_name, data_1 FROM clients WHERE ID = 257 ORDER BY ref DESC LIMIT 1`

`MAX()` will show the maximum value **for that column**. Mysql was then picking the rest of the data up from the first row.

Rather, this query will make sure you are getting the **row's** data with the highest `ref`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a having clause? This should work:

```
SELECT ref, ID, client_name, data_1 FROM clients WHERE ID = 257 having max(ref);
```

It's the best way to make a selection based on an aggregate result when you don't actually want grouping.

Comment: Thanks, but this returns `ref` of `1123` and `data_1` of `0`.  I'm confused!

Comment: Can you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE clients` to your question?

Comment: I've added to the output to the question